# Weird characters when using scapy

Tags: python, pydev, scapy

I am currently using python (in pydev) with scapy in order to send an HTTP get request to google. When I try to construct the packet however and then print the details in the console I get these funny characters:

[image]

Could any kind man tell me what these are and how to fix them?

Comment: It is worth noting that the strange characters are not really legible at this resolution. I'm guessing it's an encoding error though.

Comment: I have no idea what it is so I can only guessing - maybe it is compressed or crypted or this is how packet looks like as a string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself.

You cannot print when using scapy instead you have to use the command .show() which correctly prints the packets. 
Thanks